# The value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-0.5)^n$ is

Tags: limits

> The value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-0.5)^n$ is

What i have tried

As i know $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a)^n=0$ when $0<a<1$

If it is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(0.5)^n$ . Then it is $0$

But How do i solve for negative exponent. Help me plese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the expression under the limit as $0.5^n(-1)^n$. We see that the left term's magnitude tends to $0$ and the right term is bounded. The limit is therefore $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$-((0.5)^n) \le (-0.5)^n \le (0.5)^n.$

Squeeze.